# Assigning a function pointer with a forward-declared prototype in Nim

Tags: function-pointers, forward-declaration, nim-lang

I want to assign a Window Procedure to a Window Class structure:

```
var wndClass : WNDCLASS;

wndClass.lpszClassName = CLASSNAME;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wndClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
```

I can't assign WndProc yet because it hasn't been declared.  When I use a forward declaration (described [here](http://nim-lang.org/tut1.html#forward-declarations)):

```
proc WndProc(hWnd: HWND; msg: WINUINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM) : LRESULT
```

I get this error:

```
Error: type mismatch: got (None) but expected 'WNDPROC'
```

Is my forward declaration wrong, or do I have to write the function first in this case?

Edit:

For reference, the following code works in global scope:

```
proc Foo : int32;

var bar = Foo();
var baz = Foo;

echo bar;
echo baz();

proc Foo : int32 =
    return 4;
```

The definitions for WNDCLASS and WNDPROC can be found here:
http://nim-lang.org/windows.html

Comment: Pure speculation: Do you try to use `WndProc` in the top level global scope, or within another function? My guess would be that forward declaration only works between functions, i.e., function `A` can access `B` and vice versa if you forward declare one of them. It would make sense to me if assigning a function on top level scope requires a full definition.

Comment: I really would like to help you, but I was simply not able to reproduce your problem. It would help to have a full example, including the definitions of `WNDCLASS` and `WNDPROC`. Or even better: Can you find a minimal, cross-platform example that shows your issue?

Comment: Can `LRESULT` be accepted as type `WNDPROC` at all?

Comment: @bluenote  These are all part of the standard Nim distribution.  http://nim-lang.org/windows.html

Comment: @OderWat.  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @ilitirit I did look it up in the windows.nim file. Question was if WNDPROC really has result type LRESULT. Which leads to comparison of WNDPROC with your forward declaration. I didn't expect the pragma to be an important part either though. Was not aware that I can lookup WNDPROC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that even though the type definition of WNDPROC includes the pragmas, you have to repeat them in forward declarations.

This code compiles:

```
import windows

proc WndProc(hWnd: HWND; msg: WINUINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM) : LRESULT {.stdcall.}

var wndClass : WNDCLASS;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;

proc WndProc(hWnd: HWND; msg: WINUINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM) : LRESULT = 0
```

Incidentally, if you try to recreate the problem by including the types in the file, it fails because of case-insensitivity.